# PDF/A-1, PDF/A-2, PDF/A-3 specification

Tags: pdf, specifications

I have difficulties finding PDF/A-1, PDF/A-2, PDF/A-3 specifications. Is there one? Or is it just description of what it has? There is no trouble finding version(v1.4...v1.7) specifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your comment is an answer...why so? Yes i saw those, thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are of course, but you have to buy them from ISO,
e.g. [here for PDF/A-1](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=38920)

Then Links are at the bottom of the relevant [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A)